# opencv Code keep crashing and didn't execute afterward

Tags: pytorch, ubuntu-18.04, opencv, torchvision, python

I was working on a project that was running fine but now when I try to setup the whole code again for the client. my opencv code execute and crashes the first time I try to run it.afterwards the code doesn't even execute until I restart my system again.then code execute and crash again then it doesn't even execute. the terminal shows the msg(attached image) and nothing happen afterwards

os: ubuntu 18.04
python version: python3
opencv version 4
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, it is hard to tell you what could be happening if we don't know what's in the `test_2.py` script

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from pytroch library as te error comes from torch.nn.modules.

I recommend you to check if you have the last version of Pytorch or if there are some issue within the test_2.py code in line 139 when calling:

```
utils.predict(model_ft, labels, transforms, test_dir, imgFile)
```